# How to write data into snowflake database using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I need to write data into snowflake database, I have the below script, but I want to write data without giving username and password, is there any other way? **#NOTE - I have to run this script in databricks.**

```
import json
import snowflake.connector

# Set up the Snowflake connection parameters
conn = snowflake.connector.connect(
    user='your_username',
    password='your_password',
    account='your_account_name',
    warehouse='your_warehouse'
)

# Create a cursor object to execute SQL statements
cursor = conn.cursor()


# Assuming `json_data` contains the fetched JSON data
parsed_data = json.loads(json_data)

# Iterate through the parsed data and insert it into Snowflake
for record in parsed_data:
    # Assuming your table has columns like `column1`, `column2`, etc.
    query = f"INSERT INTO your_table (column1, column2) VALUES ('{record['key1']}', '{record['key2']}')"
    cursor.execute(query)

# Commit the changes
conn.commit()

cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Databricks secret manager:

```
user = dbutils.secrets.get("data-warehouse", "<snowflake-user>")
password = dbutils.secrets.get("data-warehouse", "<snowflake-password>")
 
options = {
  "sfUrl": "<snowflake-url>",
  "sfUser": user,
  "sfPassword": password,
  "sfDatabase": "<snowflake-database>",
  "sfSchema": "<snowflake-schema>",
  "sfWarehouse": "<snowflake-cluster>"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

how about creating environmental variables and import them

mac/linux

```
EXPORT S_USR="your_snowflake_usr"
EXPORT S_PWD="your_snowflake_pwd"
```

windows/cmd

```
set S_USR="your_snowflake_usr"
set S_PWD="your_snowflake_pwd"
```

use them in python:

```
user = os.environ.get("S_USR")
pwd = os.environ.get("S_PWD")
```

Comment: I have to run this script in databricks, this will be a automated script, which will run on a particular time everyday